# MdDatepickerModule - European format

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

I use MdDatePickerModule to pick dates but I have a problem: 
If I select August 5, everything is ok. But if I reopen the selection the month changes and becomes May, if I select May 3, I close, re-open, the month is March. Now I know that the problem is that in America the month and the day are inverted compared to Europe, but what is the "smart" way to resolve the conflict.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way of doing it for now is to set the locale as well as having a custom adapter to parse the date properly.

ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NativeDateAdapter, DateAdapter, MD_DATE_FORMATS } from "@angular/material";

export class ItalianDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  parse(value: any): Date | null {
    if ((typeof value === 'string') && (value.indexOf('/') > -1)) {
      const str = value.split('/');
      if (str.length < 2 || isNaN(+str[0]) || isNaN(+str[1]) || isNaN(+str[2])) {
        return null;
      }
      return new Date(Number(str[2]), Number(str[1]) - 1, Number(str[0]), 12);
    }
    const timestamp = typeof value === 'number' ? value : Date.parse(value);
    return isNaN(timestamp) ? null : new Date(timestamp);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-overview-example',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datepicker-overview-example.css'],
  providers: [{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: ItalianDateAdapter}],
})
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {

  locale: string;

  constructor(private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {
    this.locale = 'it';
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale('it');   
  }

}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/esZS0XnQ2Yz1Cx3rCVOF?p=preview)

This bug has been reported to Material team and being tracked by the following [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6030).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, (tried 'en-gb' and also 'it') but I have the same problem with both my code and your plunkers.

Comment: Can you fork the plunker, re-create your problem, and share the link?

Comment: I have the same problem with your plunker. If I select a day below 12, at the next reopening for the date selection the month changes according to the selected day: I select today August 5, I choose again and the month is May 2017, I select May 4, again open to choose another date and the month is April 2017 and so on. If I pick 13 or over the month it's back to August. I am Italian, here is dd / mm / yyyy. I do not change a comma to your plunkers and I always have the same problem.

Comment: Ohh, I see the problem now. I work on it, thank you!

Comment: @AntoninoMirabile, try the updated answer. I am sorry for not verifying the previous answer before posting it.

Comment: one exta point here: DateAdapter need to be imported to all modules. not only main.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with similar problem. In my app I want to use both 'en' and 'pl' date formats. All I did was adding second if() in parse method. So my adapter looks like this now:

```
export class MyDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {


  // change first day of the week to Monday(1)
  getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
    return 1;
  }

  parse(value: any): Date | null {

    // english format
    if ((typeof value === 'string') && (value.indexOf('/') > -1)) {
      const str = value.split('/');
      if (str.length < 2 || isNaN(+str[0]) || isNaN(+str[1]) || isNaN(+str[2])) {
        return null;
      }
      return new Date(Number(str[2]), Number(str[0]) - 1, Number(str[1]), 12);
    }

    // polish format
    if ((typeof value === 'string') && (value.indexOf('.') > -1)) {
      const str = value.split('.');
      if (str.length < 2 || isNaN(+str[0]) || isNaN(+str[1]) || isNaN(+str[2])) {
        return null;
      }

      return new Date(Number(str[2]), Number(str[1]) - 1, Number(str[0]), 12);
    }

    const timestamp = typeof value === 'number' ? value : Date.parse(value);
    return isNaN(timestamp) ? null : new Date(timestamp);
  }

 }
```