# Change language of Datepicker of Material Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, date, typescript, angular-material2

How to Change language of Datepicker of Material Angular?
I can't find in documentation for Angular material 2.
Here is a plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/unzlijtsHf3CPW4oL7bl?p=preview

```html
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

Comment: Are tryed to use `momentjs`? In your `main.ts` you can provide a locale settings by `{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR' }`. You should import your locale by `import 'moment/locale/fr` and after you can set locale in your datepicker component to `ngOnInit`-hook by `moment.locale('de');`. In your datepicker component you should also import moment by `import * as moment from 'moment';`

Comment: Here is a link to momentjs documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Nice idea indeed by setting     moment.locale('fr'); it should work.

Answer (score 71):

```js
import {MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material';
```

&

```js
providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'es-ES' }]
```

Do this in tpv.modules.ts

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This has the potential to be a good answer - please format your code and add your comment to the actual answer (you can edit it). :)

Comment: @antione129 Thanks, I tryed to edit it, but I'm new and I don't know how.

Comment: There is an edit link directly beneath the answer (look for some grey text, or if you really struggle. `CTRL+F` will be your ally. Someone has helped you by putting your code into blocks for you, but adding the comment to the answer would still be valuable.

Comment: This will work for the mat-datepicker UI, but this does correctly change the validation for the input field. For example, selecting Christmas on the UI will display 25/12/2018, but when you start to edit the input field, it will invalidate the form unless it's then changed to 12/25/2018.

Comment: Potentially might need to import from '@angular/material/core' if it cannot find it in the material folder. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61352498/4997466)

Answer (score 25):

md-datepicker provides `setLocale` method which can be used to set any language ([list of locale](http://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php)).

Here's an example of setting locale to 'fr':

```
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {
  
  constructor(private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale('fr');   
  }
  
}
```

One thing to keep in mind, md-datepicker's default date parsing format is `mm/dd/yyyy`, so if a locale has a different date format (for 'fr' its `dd/mm/yyyy`), we will need to define a class that extends `NativeDateAdapter` to parse the new date format. Without setting the proper date format, there will be an issue like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45524993/5556177).

```js
import { NativeDateAdapter, DateAdapter, MD_DATE_FORMATS } from "@angular/material/core";
    
export class FrenchDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  parse(value: any): Date | null {
    if ((typeof value === 'string') && (value.indexOf('/') > -1)) {
      const str = value.split('/');
      if (str.length < 2 || isNaN(+str[0]) || isNaN(+str[1]) || isNaN(+str[2])) {
        return null;
      }
      return new Date(Number(str[2]), Number(str[1]) - 1, Number(str[0]), 12);
    }
    const timestamp = typeof value === 'number' ? value : Date.parse(value);
    return isNaN(timestamp) ? null : new Date(timestamp);
  }
}

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: FrenchDateAdapter}],
})
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/M4jFuJVWHQsaYux79lWS?p=preview)

Comment: How to get the export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'ddd, MMM. D YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
}; ?

Answer (score 13):

Locale setting can be provided via MAT_DATE_LOCALE constant, but to change language dynamically you need to use DateAdapter as it is shown in https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#internationalization

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<any>) {}

  setFrench() {
    // Set language of Datepicker
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale('fr');
  }

}
```

Here is another example when you need to configure locale from external script:

```
<script>
  window.appConfig = {
    language: 'fr',
    // Other config options
    // ...
  };
<script>
<app-root></app-root>
```

In this case you should also use DateAdapter:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {DateAdapter} from '@angular/material';

declare let window: any;

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {

  appConfig = window.appConfig;

  constructor(private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<any>) {
    // Set language of Datepicker
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale(this.appConfig.language);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who has a bug when editing input field (eg: putting DD/MM/YYYY will change it to MM/DD/YYYY or simply not working) create an adapter:

```
import { NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material';

export class FrenchDateProvider extends NativeDateAdapter {

   parse(value: string) {
      let it = value.split('/');
      if (it.length == 3) {
         return new Date(+it[2], +it[1] - 1, +it[0], 12);
      }
   }

   format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object) {
      return ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
   }

}
```

Add it to your module as provider:

```
@NgModule({
   providers: [
      { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: FrenchDateProvider }
   ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: How to format for this setting?How to get the export const MY_FORMATS = { parse: { dateInput: 'LL', }, display: { dateInput: 'ddd, MMM. D YYYY', monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY', dateA11yLabel: 'LL', monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY', }, };

Answer (score 2):

For me the working solution is similar to vladernn's, however it should be:

```
import {MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';
```

and

```
providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'pl' }]
```

in material.module.ts file.

Difference: new import address and shorter `useValue` code.

Comment: Just tested and works using `angular` and `@angular/material` version 16.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked for me

```
 constructor(private _adapter: DateAdapter<any>, private translate:TranslateService ) {
 
  this._adapter.setLocale(this.translate.getBrowserLang());

 }
```