# Cannot find name "MAT_DATE_LOCALE" with Material.angular Datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material2

According to the documentation https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview here to set the locale code to one you want you provide it by putting

```
providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'},
]
```

But then my app won't compile as it tells me it cannot find the name MAT_DATE_LOCALE. Am I missing something here as in I have to define it myself? Though, I can't think of where to put it as it's all in the module class.

Comment: are you on the latest version (beta12)?

Comment: Yes, I am on the latest version.

Comment: Do `import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material';` at the top of the file.

Comment: So this worked actually. Dunno how to your comment as the answer though.

Comment: @user276648 thanks. They should write that on the documentation.

Answer (score 17):

In Angular 9 do the import:

```
 { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
```

I suppose that in the import must be entered specified path import. Optimization stuff.

Sorry for my english.

> From Angular 9, no component can be imported through @angular/material. You are to use the individual secondary entry-points, such as @angular/material/button.

[Top New Features of Angular 9](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/top-new-features-of-angular-9)

Answer (score 12):

To use MAT_DATE_LOCALE, it has to be imported explicitly like below

```
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material';
```

Please note that MAT_DATE_LOCALE should not be added to imports: [ ] array.

Answer (score 6):

When you upgrade your project dependancies from old version to new version some modules are moved into different namespaces, so you need to manually change them

i am using angular 9.1.2

I've used this

```
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
```

instead of

```
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material';
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more expressive explanation.
Could I ask where is the best place to ascertain these alterations for similar moved imports as there are a number of these changes after upgrading - where does it tell you this in the documentation?

Comment: steps that i follow:
1. Debug the code for error message
2. google the error message

Answer (score 3):

In  my case I imported this

```
import { MatInputModule, MatNativeDateModule, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
```

and in my material.module.ts I do

```
imports: [
  ....
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatNativeDateModule
],
exports: [
   ...
   MatDatepickerModule,
   MatNativeDateModule
],
providers: [
   {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'pt-BR'},
],
```

in this whay its work

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are changing the correct file.

src\app\material\material.module.ts

```
import {MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';
...
@NgModule({
  providers: [
{provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'},
 ],
```

Answer (score -1):

Had similiar issues, this is what you'll do. `import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material` the on your `@ngModule({
   import: [MatNativeDateModule]
})` this should work.