# Import statement for MAT_DATE_LOCALE in Angular 11

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular11

How can i import 'mat-date-locale' in Angular 11 modules.

I have gone through below link but no luck.

[Cannot find name "MAT_DATE_LOCALE" with Material.angular Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953742/cannot-find-name-mat-date-locale-with-material-angular-datepicker).

I have Angular Material UI in my project and here's my material Module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
// Material Form Controls
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
// Material Navigation
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
// Material Layout
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
// Material Buttons & Indicators
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
// Material Popups & Modals
import { MatBottomSheetModule } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
// Material Data tables
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatNativeDateModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatNativeDateModule
  ],
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

And this is the version information about packages used.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "mat-file-upload": "^11.1.2",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
```

"typescript": "~4.1.2"
}

Comment: Did you install `@angular/material` in your project? Meanwhile, you should provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example for showing your attempts/efforts. Either provide your code in the question or create the project on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com).

Comment: As yong says, you should install the material dependency in your project. you can do so running    npm i @angular/material.
Then, you should be able to import the constant. Please provide a stackblitz if this does not work.

Comment: updating the question

Comment: @YongShun ... My basic requirement is to change the format of Mat date picker. i want it to display date as DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

**Step 1:** Install packages via npm.

```
npm install @angular/material-moment-adapter@11
npm install moment
```

**Step 2**: Import material-theme to style.css (global stylesheet)

> style.css

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

**Step 3:** Define your date format.

> material.module.ts

```js
import {
  MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
  DateAdapter,
  MAT_DATE_LOCALE
} from '@angular/material/core';
import { MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
  }
};

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Step 4**: Add `mat-datepicker` in HTML

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"> 
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cmrtku)

---

### References

[Customizing the parse and display formats](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats)